# Custom WiFi settings screen

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am working on an app that is supposed to run as the only app available on a tablet (running android 4.2) (the launcher app just launches my app). The user has to connect to WiFi (select and enter password) and the easiest way to let the user connect to WiFi is to launch the WiFi settings Activity. But the requirement is to keep the user inside my app. So what I need is a way to have the settings inside my app, but I am not sure if that is possible? I have tried to download the source code from https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_settings/tree/jb-release/src/com/android/settings/wifi  but I am not sure if that is the way to go. It seems to be a lot of work, so before doing that I want to be sure if there is another way. Any suggestions?